# MYSQL Procedure to pivot a table to display differently

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I asked this question earlier but have reworked the structure to make more sense. I have a four tables that I use this statement to get data from

```
SELECT person.firstnames,
       person.surname,
       crm_question.label,
       crm_answer.value
       FROM crm_interaction
    JOIN person ON person.id = crm_interaction.person_id
    JOIN crm_answer ON crm_answer.interaction_id = crm_interaction.id
    JOIN crm_question ON crm_question.id = crm_answer.question_id
```

my output looks like this

```
firstnames | surname | label | value  | 
|----------|------   |-------|-----   |
|     name | surname |label 1| value 1| 
|     name | surname |label 2| value 2| 
|     name | surname |label 3| value 3|
```

But I need it to look like this

```
firstnames | surname | label 1 | label 2 | label 3 |
|----------|------   |-------   |-----    |
|     name | surname |value 1   | value 2 | value 3 | 
|     name | surname |value 1   | value 2 | value 3 |
|     name | surname |value 1   | value 2 | value 3 |
```

SOLUTION BELOW

```
SET @SQL = NULL;
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      ' max(case when crm_question.label = ''',
      label,
      ''' then crm_answer.value end) AS `',
      label, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @SQL
FROM
(
  SELECT crm_question.label AS label
  FROM crm_question
  where crm_question.label is not null and crm_question.label != ''
  ORDER BY crm_question.id
) d;

select @SQL
SET @SQL 
  = CONCAT('SELECT person.firstnames, ', @SQL, '

            from person
            join crm_interaction on crm_interaction.person_id = person.id
            join crm_answer
              on crm_answer.interaction_id = crm_interaction.id
            inner join crm_question
              on crm_question.id = crm_answer.question_id
            group by crm_interaction.id;


            ');

select @SQL
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I've removed the SQL-Server tag, because you state this a MySQL question.  SQL Server solutions won't necessary work for you.

Comment: I have figured this out, question has been updated